# Calculation of cubic Bézier with known halfway point

Tags: math, bezier

I know:

- The control points a and d (start and end point of a 2D cubic bezier curve)
- The slopes a->b, c->d, and b->c (b,c the other control points)
- Where the halfway point of the [Bézier curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) is.

Now, given this information, what is the formula for the positions of control points b and c ?

Comment: This sounds more like a math question than a programming question?

Comment: Also sounds like a homework assignment that couldn't be found via Google

Comment: Aren't many programming issues also math issues? The question sounds perfectly OK to me, and homework or not - I'd like to know the solution as well, just out of curiosity :-)

Comment: It's a question for a program of mine that deals with vector graphics. It's part of a bigger transformation but I didn't want to fill the question with irrelevant context.

Comment: Geez, aren't we allowed to have self-directed mathematical exploration these days? I've spent a lot of time fiddling around with computer graphics outside of any class. It's called LEARNING, not homework.

Comment: This seems like an overdetermined problem. Bezier curves are described by 8 degrees of freedom (one way of specifying = x,y start, x,y end, dx,dy start vector, dx,dy end vector). You have 9. (3points=6 DOF, + 3 slopes)

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but there is no correct or complete answer provided, so I thought I'd chime in with a solution. Note that David's calculations contain several errors and his solution is incomplete even if these errors are corrected.

First, define vectors `T0`, `T1` and `T2` using the three slopes:

```
T0 = ( b - a ) / u0
T1 = ( c - b ) / u1
T2 = ( d - c ) / u2
```

If we knew both the *direction* and *distance* between each pair of control points then we would not need the scale factors `u0`, `u1` and `u2`. Since we only know slope then `u0`, `u1` and `u2` are unknown scalar quantities. Also, we assume that `u0`, `u1` and `u2` are nonzero since slope is defined.

We can rewrite these equations in several different ways to obtain expressions for each control point in terms of the other control points. For example:

```
b = a + T0*u0
c = b + T1*u1
d = c + T2*u2
```

The question also states that we have the "halfway point" of the cubic Bezier curve. I take this to mean we have the point at the midpoint of the curve's parameter range. I will call this point `p`:

```
p = ( a + 3*b + 3*c + d ) / 8
```

Rewriting with unknowns on the left hand side yields:

```
b + c = ( 8*p - a - d ) / 3
```

We can now substitute for `b` and `c` in various ways using the earlier expressions. It turns out that ambiguities arise when we have parallel vectors `T0`, `T1` or `T2`. There are four cases to consider.

**Case 1: `T0` is not parallel to `T1`**

Substitute `b = a + T0*u0` and `c = a + T0*u0 + T1*u1` and solve for `u0` and `u1`:

```
2*T0*u0 + T1*u1 = ( 8*p - 7*a - d ) / 3
```

This is two equations and two unknowns since `T0` and `T1` are vectors. Substitute `u0` and `u1` back into `b = a + T0*u0` and `c = a + T0*u0 + T1*u1` to obtain the missing control points `b` and `c`.

**Case 2: `T1` is not parallel to `T2`**

Substitute `c = d - T2*u2` and `b = d - T2*u2 - T1*u1` and solve for `u1` and `u2`:

```
T1*u1 + 2*T2*u2 = ( a + 7*d - 8*p ) / 3
```

**Case 3: `T0` is not parallel to `T2`**

Substitute `b = a + T0*u0` and `c = d - T2*u2` and solve for `u0` and `u2`:

```
T0*u0 - T2*u2 = ( 8*p - 4*a - 4*d ) / 3
```

**Case 4: `T0`, `T1` and `T2` are all parallel**

In this case `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are all collinear and `T0`, `T1` and `T2` are all equivalent to within a scale factor. There is not enough information to obtain a unique solution. One simple solution would be to simply pick `b` by setting `u0 = 1`:

```
b = a + T0
(a + T0) + c = ( 8*p - a - d ) / 3
c = ( 8*p - 4*a - d - 3*T0 ) / 3
```

An infinite number of solutions exist. In essence, picking `b` defines `c` or picking `c` will define `b`.

**Extending to 3D**

The question specifically asked about planar Bezier curves, but I think it's interesting to note that the point `p` is not necessary when extending this problem to a non-planar 3D cubic Bezier curve. In this case, we can simply solve this equation for `u0`, `u1` and `u2`:

```
T0*u0 + T1*u1 + T2*u2 = d - a
```

This is three equations (the vectors are 3D) and three unknowns (`u0`, `u1` and `u2`). Substitution into `b = a + T0*u0` and `c = b + T1*u1` or `c = d - T2*u2` yields `b` and `c`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your slopes are normalized, then for some u,v you have

```
u * slope(a->b)+a = b, v * slope(c->d)+d = c
```

you know the values of a,d, and `q:=(a+b+c+d)/8` (the halfway point of the curve)
so `c = 8(q-a-d-b)`

plugging the above equations in the last one you get

```
v * slope(c->d)+d = 8(q-a-d-a-u * slope(a->b))
```

which is 2 equations (a 2d vector equation) in two variables (u,v)

You don't need the third slope.

Comment: I had arrived to something similar but the problem with this is that it doesn't give a solution when the two slopes are parallel. It involves dividing with (slope(a->b)x*slope(c->d)y - slope(a->b)y*slope(c->d)x) which is zero for parallel slopes.

Comment: Ah, now I understand, you are dealing with multiple solutions, so the 3rd slope disambiguates. Warning, it may be inconsistent w/ the remaining 8 quantities.